# Newest file in directories

Tags: bash, directory

Hi i have two directories

Directory 1:

```
song.mp3
work.txt
```

Directory 2:

```
song.mp3
work.txt
```

These files are the same, but song.mp3 in directory1 is newer than song.mp3 in directory2 and work.txt in directory 2 is newest than work.txt in directory 1.

And now how i can print in two files for example
in file1 files that are newer that in directory 2 so it must be song.mp3
and in file2 files that are newer that in directory 1 so it must be work.txt

i tried

```
find $directory1 -type f -newer $directory2
```

but it always print me the newest file in both directories. Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-newer $directory2` is just using the timestamp on the directory `$directory2` as the reference point for all the comparisons. It doesn't look at any of the files inside `$directory2`.

I don't think there's anything like a "compare each file to its counterpart in another directory" operation built in to `find`, so you'll probably have to do some of the work yourself. Here's a short script demonstrating one way it can be done:

```
(cd $directory1 && find . -print) | while IFS= read -r fn; do
  if [ "$directory1/$fn" -nt "$directory2/$fn" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "$directory1/$fn"
  else
    printf "%s\n" "$directory2/$fn"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux that supports the following:

```
Fileage=`date +%s -r filename`
```

You could run a "find" and print age in seconds followed by filename for each file and then sort that file. This has the benefit that it will work across any number of directories - not just two. Glenn's more widely available "stat -c" could be used in place of my "date" command - and he's done the "sort" and "awk" for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
# set up the test
mkdir directory1 directory2
touch directory1/song.mp3
touch -t 200101010000 directory1/work.txt
touch -t 200101010000 directory2/work.txt
touch directory2/work.txt

# find the newest of each filename:
#  sort the files in both directories by mtime
#  then only output the filename (regardless of directory) the first time seen
stat -c '%Y %n' directory[12]/* | 
sort -rn | 
cut -d " " -f 2- | 
awk -F / '!seen[$2]++'
```

```
directory2/work.txt
directory1/song.mp3
```